# Boost.Python 'too few template arguments to class_'

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I've written part of a class in C++ and I want to be able to use it in conjunction with a Python GUI, so I'm using Boost.Python to try and make it easy. The issue I'm running into is that in following their guide (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html), I keep getting the following exception whenever I run **bjam**:

```
PacketWarrior/pcap_ext.cc:21:5: error: too few template arguments for class template 'class_'
```

Obviously it's complaining at me for omitting what they claim are optional arguments to the 'class_' template function, but I can't figure out why. I'm assuming it's a compiler issue but I don't know how to fix it. I'm running OS X 10.9 and using darwin for the default toolset, but GCC throws the same error. My Boost version is 1_55_0 if that helps at all.

Class header file (header guards omitted):

```
#include <queue>
#include "pcap.h"

#include "Packet.h"

class PacketEngine {

public:
    PacketEngine();
    ~PacketEngine();

    const char** getAvailableDevices(char *error_buf);
    bool selectDevice(const char* dev);
    Packet getNextPacket();

private:
    char *selected_device;
    char **devices;
    int num_devices;
    std::queue<Packet> packet_queue;
};
```

The cc file containing the references to Boost.Python and my class:

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include "PacketEngine.h"

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pcap_ext) {
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<PacketEngine>("PacketEngine")
        .def("getAvailableDevices", &PacketEngine::getAvailableDevices);
}
```

And my bjam file (irrelevant parts and comments omitted):

```
use-project boost : ../../../Downloads/boost_1_55_0 ;

project
  : requirements <library>/boost/python//boost_python 
                 <implicit-dependency>/boost//headers 
  : usage-requirements <implicit-dependency>/boost//headers 
  ;

python-extension pcap_ext : PacketWarrior/pcap_ext.cc ;

install convenient_copy 
  : pcap_ext
  : <install-dependencies>on <install-type>SHARED_LIB <install-type>PYTHON_EXTENSION 
    <location>. 
  ;

local rule run-test ( test-name : sources + )
{
    import testing ;
    testing.make-test run-pyd : $(sources) : : $(test-name) ;
}

run-test pcap : pcap_ext pcap.py ;
```

Any ideas as to how to circumvent this exception are greatly appreciated! I looked into the obvious route of just adding the optional parameters but I don't think they're relevant to my project. The class_ definition can be found here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html

Comment: If you tag your question with [tag:boost-python], you'll maximize your chances to get some expert on the library to help you. I know very little about it but a quick google search led me to [this](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2008/07/37787.php) and it seems promising.

Comment: will do, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, include either:

- `boost/python.hpp`: The Boost.Python convenient header file.
- `boost/python/class.hpp`: The header that defines `boost::python::class_`.

The current included header files are declaring `class_` with no default template arguments from `def_visitor.hpp`.

---

Also, trying to directly expose `PacketEngine::getAvailableDevices()` will likely present a problem:

- It accepts a `char*` argument, but strings are immutable in Python.
- There are no types that automatically convert to/from a `const char**` in Boost.Python.

It may be reasonable for a Python user to expect `PacketEngine.getAvailableDevices()` to return an iterable type containing Python `str`s, or throw an exception on error.  This can be accomplished in a non-intrusive manner by writing a helper or auxiliary function that delegates to original function, but is exposed to Python as `PacketEngine.getAvailableDevices()`.

Here is a complete example based on the original code:

```cpp
#include <exception> // std::runtime_error
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace {
const char* devices_str[] = {
  "device A",
  "device B",
  "device C",
  NULL
};
} // namespace

class PacketEngine
{
public:
  PacketEngine() : devices(devices_str) {}

  const char** getAvailableDevices(char *error_buf)
  {
    // Mockup example to force an error on second call.
    static bool do_error = false;
    if (do_error)
    {
      strcpy(error_buf, "engine not responding");
    }
    do_error = true;
    return devices;
  }

private:
  const char **devices;
};

/// @brief Auxiliary function for PacketEngine::getAvailableDevices that
///        provides a more Pythonic API.  The original function accepts a
///        char* and returns a const char**.  Both of these types are
///        difficult to use within Boost.Python, as strings are immutable
///        in Python, and Boost.Python is focused to providing
///        interoperability to C++, so the const char** type has no direct
///        support.
boost::python::list PacketEngine_getAvailableDevices(PacketEngine& self)
{
  // Get device list and error from PacketEngine.
  char error_buffer[256] = { 0 };
  const char** devices = self.getAvailableDevices(error_buffer);

  // On error, throw an exception.  Boost.Python will catch it and
  // convert it to a Python's exceptions.RuntimeError.
  if (error_buffer[0])
  {
    throw std::runtime_error(error_buffer);
  }

  // Convert the c-string array to a list of Python strings.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::list device_list;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; devices[i]; ++i)
  {
    const char* device = devices[i];
    device_list.append(python::str(device, strlen(device)));
  }
  return device_list;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  python::class_<PacketEngine>("PacketEngine")
    .def("getAvailableDevices", &PacketEngine_getAvailableDevices);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> engine = example.PacketEngine()
>>> for device in engine.getAvailableDevices():
...     print device
... 
device A
device B
device C
>>> devices = engine.getAvailableDevices()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: engine not responding
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering about exposing char**, I'll have to read into Python's supported C++ types a bit more